# compare two file for match, print only one if duplicate matching found

Tags: awk

I am having two files. File1 and File2. File2 is having some duplicate entries which I cannot remove due to complexity in the file structure. Now, while generating File3 which will have a matching 1st and 2nd column between File1 and File2; i want to have only one entry from File2 for matching pattern from File1. Whats the best way to do this. I tried `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=$0;next} ($1,$2) in a{print $0}' File1 File2` but it keep all the matching entries from File2

```
File1
ab 12
cd 24
ef 56

File2
ab 12
ab 12
ef 56
```

What am getting is

```
File3
ab 12
ab 12
ef 56
```

But what I want is

```
File3
ab 12
ef 56
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete the entry from `a` after finding a matching line.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]; next} ($0 in a) {delete a[$0]; print}' File1 File2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am trying to avoid the sort command. Actually my File2 is a fastq file. Anyways thanks. I come to know a new command 'comm'

Answer (score 2):

Some more way,

Input:

```
$ cat f1
ab 12
cd 24
ef 56

$ cat f2
ab 12
ab 12
ef 56
```

Output:

```
$ awk '{k=$1 SUBSEP $2}FNR==NR{a[k]; next}k in a && !a[k]++' f1 f2
ab 12
ef 56
```

For better Readability `++a[k]==1` ( by considering thread title "compare two file for match, print only one if duplicate matching found" )

```
$ awk '{k=$1 SUBSEP $2}FNR==NR{a[k]; next}k in a && ++a[k]==1' f1 f2
ab 12
ef 56
```